# JavaScript terminate script without throw error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have site with AJAX navigation.
main.js handle AJAX navigation and few another tasks.
Some of my subpages require own scripts, lets take gallery for example.

In main.js i have function which loads gallery content and gallery.js (gallery.js is just added to head tag).
Everything works fine until i leave gallery and enter gallery again. As result i have two gallery.js working which ruin down everything.

I tried:

- remove `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gallery.js"></script>` on gallery leave but this doesn't change anything
- use `throw` but it terminate both gallery.js and main.js, so AJAX navigation die

There is way to terminate/stop gallery.js without terminate main.js?

Comment: Are you dynamically loading a page using jQuery?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to load the new page AND the page being loaded in?

Comment: Yes, i am using AJAX requests to load content.
I bind `loadContent` function to navigation elements.
This function is complex, so i will post really simplified version.

`function loadContent(url) {  "use strict"; $.ajax({ cache: true, type: 'GET',
        url: url + "content.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            changeTitle(url);
            ("#content").empty().append(data);
        },

    });`

`content.php` file:

    Some text, bla bla bla
    `$("head").append("<script src='gallery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the (properly-formatted) code there, where it's more easily visible, more easily readable and not hidden away in comments (where the lack of formatting makes it near unreadable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually more about code architecture than anything else.

Your code really should look like this

```
function loadGalleryFor(element) {
  var active = true;

  // async load here while active == true

  return { 
    stop:function() { active = false; }
    loading:function() { return active; }
  };
}
```

And you call it as:

```
var galleryCtl = loadGalleryFor(...);
```

and when you need you can stop it simply as:

```
galleryCtl.stop();
```

Comment: Looks interesting. But it won;t solve problem if i use for example:
`document.oncontextmenu = function () { return false; };` in gallery.
Because gallery.js will be still active, on whole page user will be not able to right click.
That is just example, i have more things like this, like selection disable events on scroll and others. Also if user will visit every subpage, he will have every script active. That is why i wanted to terminate script.

Comment: Instead of rewriting singletone handler you'd better subscribe to the event:
`window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) { ...
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);` 

And when needed unsubscribe the handler.

Comment: Ok, but still there is problem with multiple active not needed scripts.
Also script should do some task on load(ex. on gallery enter), that way script will fire "on load" tasks only once.
If there is no way to terminate one of scripts please just tell me, i search it in net with no result.

Comment: Concept of "terminate script" in context of JS/browsers is unclear. There are functions that are connected as event handlers. One of them may run at any given point of time. If you want to free your application from scripts originated from one source file you shall 1) stop running function (it shall issue return or be thrown away) and 2) unsubscribe all event handlers that were set by that script. After that GC in JS will be able to "free" your script.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in your comment, first check to see if the gallery script is already in the head section:

```
if ($("head>script[src='gallery.js']").length === 0) {
    $("head").append("<script src='gallery.js'></script>");
}
```

Comment: That would partly solve my problem which I've simplified.
I have subpages when i use for example:
`document.oncontextmenu = function () { return false; };` because there is a tool which require left and right mouse click actions, and few other functions which should be active only on this specific subpage.
Moreover that say gallery.js (and every script i used) still is active, i would like not to burden the user with every script on my page.
The best way would be just terminate subpage's scripts, but i do not know how to do it.